# How to evaluate MATLAB command inside SIMULINK

Tags: matlab, command, simulink

Suppose I have variable `ii` entering into the SIMULINK simulation from workspace and I would like to assign a new value for it after some condition is satisfied and save the value into a workspace. The values of variable could be defined in array, however, array length is not predefined. I see the block "MATLAB Function" could be useful, but is it proper way to evaluate just one simple command like `ii=ii+1`?

On the picture below started with `ii=0`, I expected the value of `ii` to be increased by one until `tout>2` and its value to be saved accordingly. But I only got two values of `ii`: `1` till time of 2 seconds and `0` from time > 2 seconds on.

[simulink_scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKJKz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can use simple operations avoiding use of `MATLAB Function Block`. In your case there are different solutions. For example this way:
[image]

I load `ii` variable from workspace, check the condition in `Switch` block, and return new variable with the same name `ii` to workspace.

But! Important moment here is: to load data into Simulink with `From Workspace` block loaded data must be in special format: timeseries, matrix or structure. So you can't load just `ii=1`. And the same thing about `To Workspace` block - it returns data to workspace in timeseries, array or structure. This mean you take values of `ii` for every timestep of your simulation.

You can solve this problem using `Decimation` parameter in `To Workspace` block, then you can get only last value of `ii`. To get only value of `ii` without time column use `Save format: Array` in `To Workspace` block options. This let you get just 1 value as you wish. But, now you can simulate your program only 1 time: you load `ii` with time column (as it necessary for `From Workspace` block) and save just one value. Simulink can't load now `ii` because now it hasn't time column!

So the solutions depends on what you want.

P.S. One more advice to you: do not use just `i` variable! MATLAB has predefined variable `i = 0.0000 + 1.0000i` - imaginary unit.

---

I made some workaround this problem and get this example:
[image]

Where [subsystem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/enabled-subsystems.html) is:

[image]

Attention: To Workspace block save result as `Array` (avoiding time column). How it works: create `ii=0` in workspace. Start simulation. While subsystem is enabled (`t<=2`) it will modify `ii` value in this way: increase `ii` at every timestep by 1. I mean:

```
t = 0, ii = 1
t = 1, ii = 2
t = 2, ii = 3
t = 3, ii = 3 ...
```

at the next simulation we load last value of `ii` array - `ii(end)` and continue simulation in the same way.

Comment: I have already tried to use something like you have posted, but when I want to increase variable `ii` by one according to some condition in `switch` block, the system always count with old (not incremented) value of `ii`, even if I save it by `To Workspace` block.

Comment: Let's say I would like to use `ii=ii+1` instead of `Constant` block with value of `2`. How can I do it?

Comment: I add new example to my answer. Hope it's helpful!

Comment: But why it is not working with `Constant` block (with value of 1) instead of `Ramp` block? In reality, I simply want to increase `ii` by 1 when some condition is satisfied, not according to `Ramp` slope. With `Constant` block of value 1 starting with `ii=0` I get `i=1` for all time values saved in workspace.

Comment: The answer is about timeseries again. Look carefully at the `ii` returned to workspace - it's a array, but it consists of values for each timestep. I mean `ii(1)` fit to `t=0` `ii(2) -> t=1` and so on. So how it works? Simulink take `ii(end)` check condition and add to it `1`. Ok, we get new value of `ii` for THIS current time and save it. Increase time by 1 and repeat: load `ii(end)` check condition and add 1. This means we will add 1 to all values of array `ii`! How we avoid it? Using `Ramp` block - according to the current time we add `1` or `2` or `3` and so on to current value of `ii`!